# BufferedReader readLine() blocking until buffer is full

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm writing a client/server pair of applications.  The server runs multiple threads that collect data and adds it to a BlockingQueue.  The socket code loops over the queue and sends whatever data it finds to the client.  The data is a string and I append a line separator so that the client can read it using BufferedReader.readLine().

My problem is that instead of readLine() returning on each line that's available it waits until the entire buffer is full before spitting out all the complete lines in the buffer.  With the default 8K buffer this means I get data via the client in 8K chunks, which is highly undesirable.  I've attached MRE code that represents this.  I have confirmed via logging in my actual application that the BufferedWriter is writing the data as soon as it's available from the queue, but to be honest I don't know if the delay is coming after this on the sending side, or is truly on the reading side.  If you run the MRE you'll see that the data is displayed approximately 170 lines at a time by the client.

I've searched online for this phenomenon for a couple of days and the one snippet that I could find of a similar issue suggests that maybe it's something to do with the underlying InputStreamReader and/or StreamDecoder, but that is starting to get beyond my expertise.  (See [this link](https://jvm-gaming.org/t/solved-bufferedreader-readline-unexpectedly-blocking/56569/4))

So my question is whether I'm implementing the BufferedReader correctly and how can I resolve the issue I'm seeing so that I get each incoming line without unnecessary delays.

```
package serverTest;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 54321;
        ServerSocketComms server = new ServerSocketComms(port);
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = server.getQueue();
        new Thread(server).start();
        
        ClientSocketComms client = new ClientSocketComms("localhost", port);
        new Thread(client).start();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { // should give about 10 seconds of output
            try {
                queue.put("" + i + " - All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy");
                // Slow things down enough to show what's happening
                Thread.sleep(10);
                // 48 characters should fill the 8K buffer in approximately 2 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
package serverTest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ServerSocketComms implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private final int port;
    
    public ServerSocketComms(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Open server socket and wait for connection
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Continually loop over blocking data queue until stopped
            BufferedWriter dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            while(socket.isConnected()) {
                dataOut.write(queue.take());
                dataOut.newLine(); // delimit strings with a line separator
            }
            
            // Loop never exits because client socket never completes because of BufferedReader issue
            // so sockets never close and application never terminates
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BlockingQueue<String> getQueue() {
        // Return a reference to the sending queue to be populated by other threads
        return this.queue;
    }
}
```

```
package serverTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientSocketComms implements Runnable {

    private final String server;
    private final int port;
    
    public ClientSocketComms(String server, int port) {
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Open socket to server and wait for incoming data
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
            BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            // Continually loop over incoming data until stopped
            String data;
            while((data = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
                // Should print out every line as it's received,
                // but instead waits until buffer is full
                // (outputs about 170 lines at a time)
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            
            // Close socket and thread will die
            // (but loop never ends because buffer doesn't get completely refilled)
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(socket.isConnected())` doesn't do what you think it does. It will only return `true` forever.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I know what it does, and I know that I'm using it incorrectly in this example.  This is one of those other problems that I'm aware of but which don't pertain to the issue at hand.  Blame it on cut and paste. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is using a `BufferedWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

This one does the buffering that you do not like.  It seems the default buffer size is the 8k that you are seeing although that is not documented in the API and could change.  Try flushing the buffer using `dataOut.flush()` if at some point in time you want to ensure everything stored in the buffer so far is sent out to the client immediately.  Have a look at the [BufferedWriter API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) for details.

BTW, I have not checked whether there are any other problems in your code.  But the above is definitely one.

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking at it completely wrong, not considering the issue was on the server side.  I've switched to a PrintWriter and it's working as intended now.  (There are other problems with the code, but they don't pertain to this issue.)